# Using Cucumber with JOptionPane

Tags: java, cucumber, joptionpane

So I'm completely new to testing Cucumber, and so far I love it.  I've been going through some tutorials that use Selenium with web drivers up to this point, to take input.  However, my application uses a bunch of JOptionPane for user input.

I haven't found any packages or functionality to pass data through JOptionPane.  If there isn't a way to do this, what is the best way to pass data around without a web interface (besides just directly passing parameters into my methods)? Am I totally missing the point of Cucumber by asking this?

Answer (score 0):

JOptionPane is an awt component. That is, it has nothing to do with Selenium or WebDriver.

What you want is a tool for automating a Java gui.

I wrote some stuff about that a few years ago. It is available at http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/11/01/cucumber-jvm---not-just-for-testing-guis

What I think you really are looking for is described here http://www.thinkcode.se/blog/2012/11/01/building-a-swing-gui

I used `fest-swing` for communication with the Java ui. It is an old tool that hasn't been updated for a long time. Not sure if there is anything newer or better out there.